# Plotting a simple 2D square with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]I am working n a project where I need to do the top and side views of a cube, but I don't know how to draw the square that represent the view from the top. Here is the code of the cube:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from itertools import product, combinations, cycle
from numpy import sin, cos
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle, Circle, PathPatch
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d as art3d


fig = plt.figure()  
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect("auto")
ax.set_autoscale_on(True)


#dibujar cubo
r = [-1, 1]
for s, e in combinations(np.array(list(product(r,r,r))), 2):
    if np.sum(np.abs(s-e)) == r[1]-r[0]:
        ax.plot3D(*zip(s,e), color="b")

#dibujar punto
ax.scatter([0],[0],[0],color="g",s=100)

#dibujar vector
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d

class Arrow3D(FancyArrowPatch):
    def __init__(self, xs, ys, zs, *args, **kwargs):
        FancyArrowPatch.__init__(self, (0,0), (0,0), *args, **kwargs)
        self._verts3d = xs, ys, zs

    def draw(self, renderer):
        xs3d, ys3d, zs3d = self._verts3d
        xs, ys, zs = proj3d.proj_transform(xs3d, ys3d, zs3d, renderer.M)
        self.set_positions((xs[0],ys[0]),(xs[1],ys[1]))
        FancyArrowPatch.draw(self, renderer)
#print "ingrese coordenada inicial: "
m=float(input("Ingrese valor de vector: "))
a = Arrow3D([0,0],[0,1],[0,0], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="k")
b = Arrow3D([0,-1],[0,0],[0,0], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="r")
c = Arrow3D([0,0],[0,0],[0,1], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="b")
d = Arrow3D([0,0],[0,0],[0,-1], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="g")
e = Arrow3D([0,m],[0,0],[0,0], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="c")
f = Arrow3D([0,0],[0,-0.5],[0,0], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="m")

ax.add_artist(a)
ax.add_artist(b)
ax.add_artist(c)
ax.add_artist(d)
ax.add_artist(e)
ax.add_artist(f)


a = [0, 0, 0]
b = [m, 0, 1]
orig = [0, 0, 0]
for (_b, _e), _c in zip([[orig, a], [orig, b], [a, b]], cycle(['m', 'r', 'g', 'b'])):
    xs, ys, zs = zip(_b, _e)
    res = Arrow3D(xs, ys, zs, mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="simple", color='y')
    ax.add_artist(res)

plt.show()
```

So, How can I do the top view of the cube in a subplot like the example image?

Comment: Do you have an example or reference image you could point us to?

Comment: Something like the example I update!

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution could be as simple as setting view_init().

Something like :

```
ax.view_init(0,0)
```

At the end of your code, before `plt.show()` works for me.

You can set the angle in the z-plane with elev, then the azimuth angle in the x-y plane.

From the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html) :

> **view_init**(elev=None, azim=None) Set the elevation and azimuth of the
>   axes.
>
> This can be used to rotate the axes programatically.
>
> ‘elev’ stores the elevation angle in the z plane. ‘azim’ stores the
>   azimuth angle in the x,y plane.
>
> if elev or azim are None (default), then the initial value is used
>   which was specified in the Axes3D constructor.

Comment: That's a goood one! But I really need to plot those views on different subplots in 2D.

Comment: Ok, have a look at the sub-plot [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=subplot#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot). Post what you have tried and where it is failing.